# Error: knex: Required configuration option 'client' is missing with docker

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, knex.js

I have been researching to find the solution for many hours. When I try to run knex migrate: latest in my docker. It always gives me :

> Error: knex: Required configuration option 'client' is missing with docker

I have tried a lot of solutions for the stack overflow, but it seems not to work.

Docker.file

```docker
FROM node:16-alpine
RUN npm install -g nodemon

RUN npm install -g knex
#tell docker to run configure in this app directory
WORKDIR /app
#copy source code into the image
#copy our current direct to new folder call app



COPY package.json.
RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force

COPY . .
ENV NODE_ENV=local
EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["knex", "migrate:latest"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.8"
#project name API does not have to be the same name
services:
  back_end:
   #find docker file in our code to build it
    build: .
  #automatically create container back_end_c
    container_name: back_end_c
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    volumes:
      #map currendirect to /app of docker
      - .:/app
      #maksure node modules app container does not delete.
      - ./app/node_modules
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "4321:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: me
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: api
```

knexfile.js

```js
// // Update with your config settings.
require('dotenv').config();
const config = {
  development: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      user: 'me',
      host: 'localhost',
      database: 'api',
      password: 'password',
      port: 5432,

    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: __dirname + '/migrations',
    }
  },
  
  staging: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      user: 'me',
      host: 'db',
      database: 'api',
      password: 'password',
      port: 5432, 
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  },

  production: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
      ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  }
};

module.exports = config
```

db.js (file connect knex)

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const knex = require('knex');
const knexfile = require('../knexfile');
let db = null;

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'local'){
    console.log("local");
    console.log("local2");
    console.log(knexfile.development);
    db = knex(knexfile.development);
   
}else{
    console.log("produdction");
    db = knex(knexfile.production)
}
module.exports = db;
```

Comment: Does it log the `development` config?

Comment: _`ENV NODE_ENV=local`_  is this meant to be `local` and not one of `development`, `staging` or `production`?

Comment: That is just env args. It works fine

Comment: Matt: Yes it does log development config